# How to Activate Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-activation

I can't figure out that my Windows is genuine or not. I have key but I can't find from where I can activate it. I have done this so many times in past but this time I can't find any thing at `'My Computer -> Properties'` Please see image.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

everything key and activation related can be done via command line with the [slmgr command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793433.aspx)

open a cmd (start, run, cmd, enter)
and type

```
slmgr.vbs /ipk [YOURKEY]
```

Comment: 'slmgr.vbs' is not recognized as internal or external command

Comment: weird, its available on my windows 7 (i have one professional and one ultimate edition here)...  maybe this is an entirely different issue. please try the command with the full path (C:\Windows\system32\slmgr.vbs)

Comment: There is one directory with name 'slmgr' and one file 'slmgr.vbs.removewat' in system32. In 'slmgr' director there is another directory '0409' and this directory has slmgr.ini file.

Comment: "slmgr.vbs.removewat" is created when you use an activation removal tool called RemoveWAT. This indicates that your copy of Windows 7 is illegal.

Comment: That solved first part of the problem now I want to make it legal but don't know how?

Comment: @MuhammadKashifNadeem - Buy a license? lol.

Comment: @MuhammadKashifNadeem - At this point since you know your installation is not legal, you cannot trust the installation itself, I would purchas a license from Microsoft and reinstall your entire operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You can reactivate your Windows 7 by performing the following:

- Click on the Start button and in the Start Search box type `slui.exe`.
- Press the Enter key on your keyboard.
- Select your Country.
- Follow the instructions for phone activation (no charge).

Hope it helps.

Comment: He has software to block the WPA service.  His only solution is to perform a format and reinstall from an authenticate installation.

Comment: @Ramhound why is this? I have purchased a license from MS. I installed Windows. After installation I tried to install drivers but I could not find these on vendor's site so I handed over this to local vendor from where I purchased my system. They installed drivers and after that I tried to activate Windows but unable to do this. Reinstalling is nightmare because I already have installed so my software.

Comment: I cant run 'slui.exe'